# How to retrieve td input textbox value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the follwing table,on click function(removeRow), I want to retrieve value of textbox (txtTotalAmount).

I wrote this

```
function removeRow(name) { 
  $(name).parent().parent().remove(); 
  var total = $(name).parent().parent().siblings().find("input .classTotalAmount").val();
  alert(total);// shows only undefined in alert box 
}
```

Here is my table

```
    <table id="tblitems" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="additemtb">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
          <th>Item Name</th>
          <th>Item Code</th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Qty</th>
          <th>UOM</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Minimal Order Qty</th>
          <th>FOC</th>
          <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td style="width:90px;">
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="copy" onclick="copyRow(this);">Copy</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="delete" onclick="removeRow(this);">delete</a>
              <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add" onclick="addRows(this)">add</a>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td >Total Amount</td>
          <td>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotalAmount" CssClass="classTotalAmount number" Columns="8" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" CssClass="classCurrency3" />
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: which table? put the html code

Answer (score 0):

```
var amount = $("#txtTotalAmount").val();
```